# How can I have a SQL Query using String.Format in VBA (Excel)

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'll have a query, lets say something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN {1} AND {2}"
```

Once I have it, I have to put my own dates, something like:

```
String.Format("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN {1} AND {2}", Date1, Date2)
```

Merci in advance!

Comment: You definitely shouldn't build SQL query using string concatenation. It is a subject to **SQL injection**.

Comment: You'd have to use `Replace`: `Replace(Replace("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN {1} AND {2}", "{1}", Date1), "{2}", Date2)`

Comment: Which RDBMS (product and version)? You might think of `REPLACE` (but be aware of DateTime formats! Or you might think about parameters (better!)

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown does works fine. Just that the place holder variable starts at 0. Your code line should look like below considering that `Date1` and `Date2` are datetime variable and does exists.

```
String.Format("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN {0} AND {1}", Date1, Date2)
```

Comment: Not in VBA it doesn't.

Comment: @Rory, Ahh!! does VBA has `String.Format`? I doubt that. OP's posted code looks to be C# code rather.

Comment: No it doesn't. The question specified Excel VBA.

Comment: @Rory, That's strange actually and to me it looks like a mistake from OP's end.

Comment: Why? He appears just to be asking how to do the equivalent in VBA.